# MySQL GROUP BY and ORDER BY question

Tags: php, mysql

I have a messaging system which needs to be ordered correctly.  When a post is created, it is automatically assigned a thread ID (for whatever thread it belongs to).

I'm currently grouping the posts under their thread ID like this:

```
   SELECT 
      *
   FROM 
      `Posts`
   INNER JOIN
      `Profiles`
   ON
      `Profiles`.`ID` = `Posts`.`Sender`
   GROUP BY     
      `Posts`.`ThreadID`
   ORDER BY 
      `Posts`.`ID` DESC
```

What I want to happen is for the most recently updated THREAD to be displayed first in the list.  So, say if a post for Thread C has just been made, Thread C will display first (before Thread A or Thread B).  I didn't know what to put for `ORDER BY`.

Does anybody know if this is possible?

Comment: What's the table definition for `Posts`?

Comment: What are the fields in the Post table? you can order by posting date, if it's available.

Comment: Currently, you are only selecting 1 post for every thread.. Are you aware of that?

Comment: I thought that was the case - is there any way to select every post from a thread and then order the threads according to the newest post?

Comment: @jamie, Yes, but why the `GROUP BY`

Comment: If you want to order by time, you need to have a time field in there somewhere.

Comment: @The Scrum Meister, because I wanted to display every thread rather than every individual post. I thought grouping the posts together under their thread ID would display threads rather than a list of every post. Is that incorrect?

Comment: @jamie If you want to display a list of threads, and for each thread 1 random post, then use the first part of my answer. If you want to display all the posts, but sorted together by Thread, and the threads them self, sorted by most recent, then use the second query in my answer. Otherwise, please post in your question how you want the results to look.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT *
FROM `Posts` INNER JOIN `Profiles` ON
  `Profiles`.`ID` = `Posts`.`Sender`
GROUP BY     
  `Posts`.`Thread`
ORDER BY 
  MAX(`Posts`.`ID`) DESC
```

---

**Updated**: 
If you want to get all the posts for each thread and show the most recent threads on top:

```
SELECT p.*, pf.*
FROM Posts p JOIN `Profiles` pf ON pf.ID = p.Sender
  JOIN (
 SELECT Thread, MAX(ID) MaxPost
 FROM Posts
 GROUP BY Thread) po ON p.Thread = po.Thread
ORDER BY po.MaxPost DESC, p.ID DESC
```

Comment: This wont work, the grouping doesn't allow for different users (profiles) you will get an essentially random post returned within each thread

Comment: @developerchris See my comments on the question.

Comment: The updated code results in "Mysql error: Unknown column 'po.ThreadID' in 'on clause'". I want the threads to display, and I want them ORDERED by their most recent post. So, say I submit a new post in Thread C, Thread C will then be ordered at the top.

Comment: @jamie I just ran the updated code on machine, works fine. unless you do not have a column named `ThreadID` in your `posts` table? If so, Please post the table definitions in your question!

Comment: The column names for the `Posts` table are as follows: ID, Date, Sender, Recipient, Body, Subject, thread

Comment: @jamie Updated. In the future, you need to post the table definitions in your question, we are not mind readers. **Specially, when the code you posted in the question shows that the column is named `ThreadID`**